# Regex for mobile number with special characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to validate mobile numbers that accepts **()**,**-** and **+**. I am totally new to this and this is what I could build

```
\+?\(?([0-9])\)?[- ]?\(?([0-9])\)?
```

But I know this wrong since it is accepting data such as **123456-** which is not right.
Can somebody please help me build a regex so that itdoes not accept inputs like

```
123)3575
12349-
-2345678
```

There is no limit to the number of digits entered. I'm expecting it to accept inputs of type

```
(123)4567-67898
+234567890
1234-4567-67
```

Please help..

Comment: You might need to be a bit more definite about which formulas are acceptable and which aren't.  For instance, would `9-3-5-23-4` be acceptable?  Can a parenthesised group of numbers or a + only appear at the beginning of a number?  Unless you can be clearer about what is and is not allowed, it will be hard to give you a good answer.  If you can be very clear, you will almost have solved the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
/^(\+|\(\d+\))?\d+(-\d+)*$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cE2wF3/1)

**Test**

```
Regex.IsMatch("(123)4567-67898", @"^(\+|\(\d+\))?\d+(-\d+)*$");
=> True

Regex.IsMatch("-2345678", @"^(\+|\(\d+\))?\d+(-\d+)*$");
=> False
```